# How to use `while read` (Bash) to read the last line in a file if there’s no newline at the end of the file?

Tags: bash, newline, eof

Let’s say I have the following Bash script:

```
while read SCRIPT_SOURCE_LINE; do
  echo "$SCRIPT_SOURCE_LINE"
done
```

I noticed that for files without a newline at the end, this will effectively skip the last line.

I’ve searched around for a solution [and found this](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/SuSE/2008-11/msg00237.html):

> When read reaches end-of-file instead
>   of end-of-line, it does read in the
>   data and assign it to the variables,
>   but it exits with a non-zero status.
>   If your loop is constructed "while
>   read ;do stuff ;done
>
> So instead of testing the read exit
>   status directly, test a flag, and have
>   the read command set that flag from
>   within the loop body. That way
>   regardless of reads exit status, the
>   entire loop body runs, because read
>   was just one of the list of commands
>   in the loop like any other, not a
>   deciding factor of if the loop will
>   get run at all.
>
> ```
> DONE=false
> until $DONE ;do
> read || DONE=true
> # process $REPLY here
> done < /path/to/file.in
> ```

How can I rewrite this solution to make it behave exactly the same as the `while` loop I was having earlier, i.e. without hardcoding the location of the input file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your first example, I'm assuming you are reading from *stdin*. To do the same with the second code block, you just have to remove the redirection and echo $REPLY:

```
DONE=false
until $DONE ;do
read || DONE=true
echo $REPLY
done
```

Comment: Ah, the redirection was confusing me. Thanks for your answer, it works like a charm!

Comment: To keep from processing an extra (empty) line if there *is* a final newline, add this after the line that includes `read`: `[[ ! $REPLY ]] && continue`

Comment: @Dennis: That seems to skip all the empty lines, which is exactly what I want in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 47):

I use the following construct:

```
while IFS= read -r LINE || [ -n "$LINE" ]; do
    echo "$LINE"
done
```

It works with pretty much anything except null characters in the input:

- Files that start or end with blank lines
- Lines that start or end with whitespace
- Files that don't have a terminating newline

Comment: You don't need to include a newline in IFS; you can simply set it to the empty string.  Also, to make this POSIX compliant (currently it only works in bash, not `/bin/sh`), do `IFS='' read -r LINE || [ -n "$LINE" ]`

Comment: Beware that this adds an additional newline at EOF if there is none already.

Answer (score 6):

Using `grep` with while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
done < <(grep "" file)
```

Using `grep .` instead of `grep ""` will skip the empty lines.

Note:

1. Using `IFS=` keeps any line indentation intact.
2. [You should almost always use the -r option with read.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
3. File without a newline at the end isn't a standard unix text file.

Comment: Adding on the 3rd note: This is how the POSIX standard defines a line (Line 3206): https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206

Answer (score 5):

Instead of *read*, try to use *GNU Coreutils* like *tee*, *cat*, etc.

from stdin

```
readvalue=$(tee)
echo $readvalue
```

from file

```
readvalue=$(cat filename)
echo $readvalue
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the pattern I've been using:

```
while read -r; do
  echo "${REPLY}"
done
[[ ${REPLY} ]] && echo "${REPLY}"
```

Which works because even tho' the `while` loop ends as the "test" from the `read` exits with a non-zero code, `read` still populates the inbuilt variable `$REPLY` (or whatever variables you choose to assign with `read`).

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue here is that `read` will return errorlevel 1 when it encounters EOF, even if it'll still correctly feed the variable.

So you can use errorlevel of `read` right away in your loop, otherwize, the last data won't be parsed. But you could do this:

```
eof=
while [ -z "$eof" ]; do
    read SCRIPT_SOURCE_LINE || eof=true   ## detect eof, but have a last round
    echo "$SCRIPT_SOURCE_LINE"
done
```

If you want a very solid way to parse your lines, you should use:

```
IFS='' read -r LINE
```

Remember that:

- NUL character will be ignored
- if you stick to using `echo` to mimick the behavior of `cat` you'll need to force an `echo -n` upon EOF detected (you can use the condition `[ "$eof" == true ]`)

Answer (score 1):

for reading files with or without a newline at the end:

```
cat "somefile" | { cat ; echo ; } | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

Source : My open source project https://sourceforge.net/projects/command-output-to-html-table/

Answer (score 0):

@Netcoder's answer is good, this optimisation eliminates spurious blank lines, also allows for the last line not to have a newline, if that's how the original was.

```
DONE=false
NL=
until $DONE ;do
if ! read ; then DONE=true ; NL='-n ';fi
echo $NL$REPLY
done
```

I used a variant of this to create 2 functions to allow piping of text that includes a '[' to keep grep happy. (you can add other translations)

```
function grepfix(){
    local x="$@";
    if [[ "$x" == '-' ]]; then
      local DONE=false
      local xx=
      until $DONE ;do
         if ! IFS= read ; then DONE=true ; xx="-n "; fi
         echo ${xx}${REPLY//\[/\\\[}
      done
    else
      echo "${x//\[/\\\[}"
    fi
 }


 function grepunfix(){
    local x="$@";
    if [[ "$x" == '-' ]]; then
      local DONE=false
      local xx=
      until $DONE ;do
         if ! IFS= read ; then DONE=true ; xx="-n "; fi
         echo ${xx}${REPLY//\\\[/\[}
      done
    else
      echo "${x//\\\[/\[}"
    fi
 }
```

(passing - as $1 enables pipe otherwise just translates arguments)