# Reading input files by line using read command in shell scripting skips last line

Tags: bash, parsing, shell, file-io

I usually use the read command to read an input file to the shell script line by line. An example code such as the one below yields a wrong result if a new line isn't inserted at the end of the last line in the input file, blah.txt.

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line
do
echo $line
done <blah.txt
```

So if the input file reads something like -

```
One 
Two
Three
Four
```

and I do not hit return after Four, the script fails to read the last line, and prints

```
One
Two
Three
```

Now if I leave an extra blank line after Four, like,

```
One 
Two
Three
Four
//blank line
```

the output prints all the lines, including Four. However, this is not the  case when I read a line using the `cat` command; all lines including the last get printed without me having to add an extra blank line at the end.

Anyone has ideas on why this happens? The scripts I create will mostly be run by others, so it isn't necessary they're going to add an extra blank line at the end of every input file.

I've been trying to figure this out for ages; I'd appreciate it if you have any solutions(of course, the `cat` command is one, but I'd like to know the reason behind read not working as well).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`read` reads until it finds a newline character or the end of file, and returns a non-zero exit code if it encounters an end-of-file. So it's quite possible for it to both read a line and return a non-zero exit code.

Consequently, the following code is not safe if the input might not be terminated by a newline:

```
while read LINE; do
  # do something with LINE
done
```

because the body of the `while` won't be executed on the last line.

Technically speaking, a file not terminated with a newline is not a text file, and text tools may fail in odd ways on such a file. However, I'm always reluctant to fall back on that explanation.

One way to solve the problem is to test if what was read is non-empty (`-n`):

```
while read -r LINE || [[ -n $LINE ]]; do
  # do something with LINE
done
```

Other solutions include using `mapfile` to read the file into an array, piping the file through some utility which is guaranteed to terminate the last line properly (`grep .`, for example, if you don't want to deal with blank lines), or doing the iterative processing with a tool like `awk` (which is usually my preference).

Note that `-r` is almost certainly needed in the `read` builtin; it causes `read` to not reinterpret `\`-sequences in the input.

Comment: I like the `grep .` solution.  Nice and simple.

Comment: @rici what does `||` and `[[ -n $LINE ]]`  mean here? does `||` mean  Or?

Comment: @Unknown: It means "or" in the sense that `cmd1 || cmd2` succeeds if either `cmd1` succeeds or `cmd2` succeeds. (Success means an exit code of 0.) `read` succeeds if it encounters a newline character; `[[` succeeds if the test expression (in this case `$LINE` is not empty) is true.

Comment: Well done, you may want to mention what the `-n` test actually tests for -- it tests if the length of the string is non-zero. Same as `[[ ! -z "${LINE}" ]]`.

Answer (score 8):

```
DONE=false
until $DONE
do
  read line || DONE=true
  echo $line
done < blah.txt
```

[How to use `while read` (Bash) to read the last line in a file if there’s no newline at the end of the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4165135/how-to-use-while-read-bash-to-read-the-last-lin)

Answer (score 8):

Use while loop like this:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
  echo "$line"
done <file
```

Or using `grep` with while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
done < <(grep "" file)
```

Using `grep .` instead of `grep ""` will skip the empty lines.

Note:

1. Using `IFS=` keeps any line indentation intact.
2. [You should almost always use the -r option with read.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
3. [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)
4. File without a newline at the end isn't a standard unix text file.

Comment: Thanks!  First option did not work for me on macOS 13.0, but the second one did.

Answer (score 4):

One line answer:

```
IFS=$'\n'; for line in $(cat file.txt); do echo "$line" ; done
```

Comment: won't work if you have spaces in the line - will treat as a separate line

Comment: Thanks schmi for your comment you are right, I edited the answer and putted IFS=$'\n'; first this tell cat command to only use newline as separator. The answer remains one line :)

Comment: This changes the `IFS` of the current shell. [And you shouldn't read lines with for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: You can change IFS later with unset IFS, about efficiency for performs good it only requires more memory like twice the file size because it hold it entirely en memory but with today's advances memory is cheap and not a problem. I agree with you that with big files is better to use a while, my answer was just to show a one line approach to the problem that is something that many people want: simplicity

Answer (score 0):

Below code with Redirected "while-read" loop works fine for me

```
while read LINE
do
      let count++
      echo "$count $LINE"

done < $FILENAME

echo -e "\nTotal $count Lines read"
```