# bash while loop drops last line of text file

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

when i cat this file I get 6 lines (it is a diff file)

```
bash-3.00$ cat /tmp/voo
18633a18634
> sashabSTP
18634a18636
> sashatSTP
21545a21548
> yheebash-3.00$
```

however when i read it line by line i only get 5 lines.

```
bash-3.00$ while read line ; do echo $line ; done < /tmp/voo
18633a18634
> sashaSTP
18634a18636  
> sashatSTP
21545a21548
```

or this

```
bash-3.00$ cat /tmp/voo | while read line ; do  echo $line ; done
18633a18634
> sashabSTP
18634a18636
> sashatSTP
21545a21548
bash-3.00$
```

i am missing the last line 'yhee' from the while loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note:

```
21545a21548
> yheebash-3.00$
      ^---- no line break
```

Your file doesn't terminate with a line break.

Comment: yo got it - the output is cron driven - i guess i will add an echo command to the last line.

Comment: You can also make the `while` loop run for the unterminated final line by using `while read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do` (see [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916352/shell-script-read-missing-last-line/12919766#12919766)).

Answer (score 3):

If you are wondering *why?*, [this might satisfy your curiosity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12916758/3744681).

If you work with files which may or may not end up with a new line at end, you can do this:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
  echo "$line"
done <file
```

Or this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
done < <(grep "" file)
```

Read more:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31397497/3744681
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31398490/3744681

Comment: The second option solved a problem for me where the while loop was reading the same line multiple times in a CSV file. Thanks for the tip!