# Bash while/read -d loop drops last element

Tags: bash

Why does my `while` loop skip the last element? I see similar discussion for cases where trailing newlines are missing (e.g. [bash while loop drops last line of text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359553/bash-while-loop-drops-last-line-of-text-file)) but it doesn't seem this applies to `read -d`.

```
$ IP=1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8
$ while read -d : -r part; do echo $part; done <<< $IP
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

I'm using GNU bash 4.2.

Comment: You need a trailing `:` for the final `read` command to report success. The duplicate questions' answers really are applicable; appending `|| [[ $part ]]` as they recommend will fix your problem here.

Comment: It's exactly the same reason as that other question. You've simply replaced the default newline with `:`.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it was somehow less clunky. Feel free to copypasta to answers and I'll accept.