# While loop skips the first line in output

Tags: unix, hash, while-loop

I'm using the below command in Terminal on a Mac to read a file of email addresses and convert them to a MD5 hash.

```
tr -d " " < em.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | while read line; do 
(echo -n $line | md5); done | awk '{print $1}' > hashes1.txt
```

This produces a file of hashes that are 1 row shorter than the original input file. But I can't figure out why.

This code does a few things, below.

1. Converts an email address to all lower case
2. Converts the email address to a MD5 Hash
3. Outputs a list of new email addresses to a hashes1.txt file

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your [tr](/questions/tagged/tr) command is wrong : it should be :

```
tr -d " " < em.txt |
    tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]' |
    while IFS= read -r line; do 
        echo -n "$line" | md5 | awk '{print $1}' >> hashes1.txt
    done
```

or

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    echo -n "$line" | md5 | awk '{print $1}' >> hashes1.txt
done < <(tr -d " " < em.txt | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]')
```

Changed the file feeding place too.

And ensure your file don't have strange characters with

```
od -c file
```

if yes, install `dos2unix`, then :

```
dos2unix file
```

or using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -i -pe 's/\r//g' file
```

Comment: Thanks. When I use that script, it still ends up 1 row shorter. But this time it cuts off the last row. I can tell it's cutting off the last row because I remove "| md5" to check and the last email is cut off.

Comment: Try `od -c file` to see if you don't have strange characters, like windows line endings `\r\n` : change it if it's the case : `dos2unix file`

Comment: Yes, you are right. The file has \r\n. But when I try to use dos2unix I get the below error"-bash: dos2unix: command not found". Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Or use : `perl -i -pe 's/\r//g' file`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I get this error when I try to install brew "-bash: brew: command not found". But one other question. If I remove '\r\n', then will my text file become 1 long text string instead of separate email addresses?

Comment: Perl command works great, and the file no longer as \r characters. But, the script still drops the last row in the output, unfortunately. So my output file is always 1 row shorter than the input file with the hashing.

Comment: Without seeing the file, I can't do nothing more

Comment: Can you test my new snippet from my answer ? Is it better ?

Comment: Tested it. Unfortunately, it still cuts off the last line. :(

Comment: `while read line` reads up to a newline. When the last line is without a newline, it will be skipped. Fixes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31397497/3220113 (also use `IFS=` and `read -r` for other reasons)

Comment: You didn't add `|| [ -n "$line" ]` for the last incomplete line, but an upvote for all your effort.