# why process substitution does not always work with while loop in bash?

Tags: bash, process, while-loop, substitution

The [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) works with filenames fine, e.g. both

```
$ cat <FILENAME
```

and

```
$ while read i; do echo $i; done <FILENAME
```

work.

But if instead of FILENAME we use `echo` command (or any other, which generates output to stdout), `cat` continues to work

```
$ cat <(echo XXX)
XXX
```

while the loop

```
$ while read i; do echo $i; done <(echo XXX) 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<(echo XXX)'
```

produces error.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Note:** `<filename` is *not* process substitution. It's a [redirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections). Process substitution has the format `<(command)`.

Process substitution substitutes the *name of a process* for the `<(...)`. Despite the use of the <kbd><</kbd> symbol, it is not a redirect.

So when you say `cat <(echo foo)`, bash creates a subprocess to run the `echo` command, and substitutes the name of a pseudo-file which can be read to get the output of that command. The result of the substitution will be something like this:

```
cat /dev/fd/63
```

Note the absence of a redirect. (You can see this in action by typing `echo <(echo foo)`.)

Like many utilities, `cat` can be invoked with or without a command-line argument; if no file is specified, then it reads from `stdin`. So `cat file.txt` and `cat < file.txt` are very similar.

But the `while` command does not accept additional arguments. So

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < file.txt
```

is valid, but

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done file.txt
```

is a syntax error.

Process substitution doesn't change that. So

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done /dev/fd/63
```

is a syntax error, and consequently so is

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done <(echo foo)
```

To specify the redirect from the process substitution, you need a redirect:

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < <(echo foo)
```

Note that there must be a space between the two <kbd><</kbd> symbols to avoid confusion with the "here-doc" syntax, `<<word`.

Comment: What a rollercoaster! "Had us in the first half, not gonna lie" – right up until the last line I thought I was reading bad news. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I apologize for stupidity, just have found the working solution

```
$ while read i; do echo $i; done < <(echo XXX)
XXX
```

I will be really thankfull if somebody can explain the idea behind this strange syntax with double less sign, `< <`.

Comment: That's no stupidity. You assumed precisely what one should be able to assume. That your assumption was wrong speaks more against the designers of the `bash` language than against you.

Comment: Thank you for leaving this comment!! I tried two << and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. I think this comment is very smart.

Answer (score 2):

The process substitution operation generates a file name, usually in `/dev/fd` though that isn't mandated.  It needs to be thought of in those terms; it can be used where a file name can be used.

You can see what it does with, for example:

```
echo <(cat /etc/passwd)
```

Your examples show this.  The `cat` command accepts file name arguments.  The `done` keyword does not accept file name arguments, but does accept I/O redirection.

You can decide that the notation is confusing; in some respects, it is.  But there is little point in complaining.  That is the way Bash does it.  You are at liberty to create your own shell using a different notation, but Bash will continue to support the current notation for reasons of backwards compatibility.