# BASH - While loop error

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

With this code i get this error, and my function is not available:

> Erreur de syntaxe près du symbole inattendu « < » `done < <(echo -e
>   "$TARGET_PORTS")' warning: syntax errors in . or eval will cause
>   future versions of the shell to abort as Posix requires

```
   function my_func{ 
    while read Port
    do
            CHECK_HG=`raidcom get host_grp -port $Port -IH${CCI_INST} |grep -iw ${HOST}`
            if [ ! -z "$CHECK_HG" ]; then
                    export HMO=`raidcom get host_grp -port $Port -IH${CCI_INST} | grep -i ${HOST} | awk -F " " '{print \$5}'`
                    if [ $HMO == "LINUX/IRIX" ]; then
                            HMO=`echo $HMO | awk -F "/" '{print \$1}'`
                    fi
                    #comment
                    NBPort=`expr $NBPort + 1`
                    #comment
                    PORT_HG=$PORT_HG"$Port;\n"
                    fi
    done < <(echo -e "$TARGET_PORTS")
}
```

So when i change my loop, i get no error, I but loses all data in the variable to recover in the main script.

```
function my_func{
    echo -e "$TARGET_PORTS" | while read Port
    do
            CHECK_HG=`raidcom get host_grp -port $Port -IH${CCI_INST} |grep -iw ${HOST}`
            if [ ! -z "$CHECK_HG" ]; then
                    export HMO=`raidcom get host_grp -port $Port -IH${CCI_INST} | grep -i ${HOST} | awk -F " " '{print \$5}'`
                    if [ $HMO == "LINUX/IRIX" ]; then
                            HMO=`echo $HMO | awk -F "/" '{print \$1}'`
                    fi
                    #comment
                    NBPort=`expr $NBPort + 1`
                    #Comment
                    PORT_HG=$PORT_HG"$Port;\n"
                    fi
    done
}
```

Any idea?
Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe try remove one '<' at the end of while loop.

Comment: No... same error with: done < (echo -e "$TARGET_PORTS" ) or done <(echo -e "$TARGET_PORTS" )

Comment: You're executing the script with a shell other than `bash`, and that shell does not understand process substitution.

Comment: Simpler: `for Port in $TARGET_PORTS;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirection looks right for a bash script, it has the format as explained on https://stackoverflow.com/a/28927847/3220113.
Can you add a shebang (`#!/bin/bash` on the first line of the script), trying to force it into bash?

Another solution (nice when you need to run the same script in ksh on AIX/Solaris and in bash) is changing the while into a for-loop:

```
for Port in $(echo -e "$TARGET_PORTS") do
   ...
done
```

Comment: thank you chepner, the script was launch with sh "Path/script...." . With bash "Path/script...." its work!