# while read loop with input from process substitution not exiting on break in zsh

Tags: zsh, process-substitution

Using zsh, I was trying to break the while loop after file move event, but break happens only after the second one. This only occurs when I try to execute script

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

while read changed; do
  echo $changed
  if [ $changed = MOVE_SELF ]; then
    echo "File was moved."
    break
  fi
done < <(inotifywait -m -e move_self --format "%e" $1)

echo "HI THERE"
```

in zsh. However, if I try the same code with `#!/bin/bash` it works as expected (loop breaks after the first event).

Comment: I'd suggest tagging this only zsh and not bash; the bash behavior is well-understood, so you need only zsh experts looking at this question, not bash experts.

Comment: @rowboat, Thank you. `<(... &)` works fine. Would you mind writing an answer? I need `-m`, example above is simplified.

Comment: May I ask why you have two `<` signs for the process substitution, i.e. `done < <(inotify ...)`? I would have expected only one.

Comment: @user1934428, Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28927847/15036204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behavior in zsh and bash is different. One of the possible solutions is to use `&` for command in process substitution. Diff:

```bash
< done < <(inotifywait -m -e move_self --format "%e" $1)
---
> done < <(inotifywait -m -e move_self --format "%e" $1 &)
```

Looks like zsh is blocking waits for process substitution to execute again. Output of `zsh -x` after first execution of `inotitywait` without `&`:

```
+script.sh:3> read -r changed
+script.sh:3> inotifywait -m -e move_self --format %e file.lua
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
+script.sh:4> echo MOVE_SELF
MOVE_SELF
+script.sh:5> [ MOVE_SELF '=' MOVE_SELF ']'
+script.sh:6> echo 'File was moved.'
File was moved.
+script.sh:7> break
```