# How to get file from POST data in Bash CGI script?

Tags: bash, curl, cgi

I am trying to post a file using cURL and receive it on the other side via a CGI Bash script and store it with the same name. After upload is completed, `diff` between the original file and reconstructed one should return zero.

The way cURL sends data:

```
curl --request POST --data-binary "@dummy.dat" 127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/upload-rpm
```

Receiver script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
echo '<title>Foo</title>'
echo '</head>'
echo '<body>'

echo "<p>Start</p>"

if [ "$REQUEST_METHOD" = "POST" ]; then
    echo "<p>Post Method</p>"
    if [ "$CONTENT_LENGTH" -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "<p>Size=$CONTENT_LENGTH</p>"
        while read -n 1 byte -t 3; do echo -n -e "$byte" >> ./foo.dat ; done
    fi
fi
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'

exit 0
```

But it's not working. File is not created on the server side. And how can I get the file name?

Comment: You could get the file name by specifying a custom header on the sending side and then including it in the request.  i.e. `curl -H "x-filename: foo.dat"`.  Regarding the debugging of the write script, perhaps add `-x` to the shebang and see if you can catch where the script is exiting.  One more thing - reading 1 byte at a time via `read` would be very slow.  What is the cgi program that is setting the variables that your receive script is using to process the data ?

Comment: What is your server? (apache, nginx, netcat, other)?? The file is recieved by your server first, then passed to CGI script as *internal* data, in a way depending on server and version of server.

Comment: Care! Using [tag:bash] for *CGI scripting* seem very unsecure!!!

Comment: @F.Hauri It's Apache 2

Comment: At line 2 of your script, add  `echo "$0 -- $@" >/tmp/trace-cgi-$$.txt ; set >>/tmp/trace-cgi-$$.txt` this will help you to see how environment variables are populated by apache, befor running CGI.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

as long as you're always uploading exactly 1 file using the `multipart/form-data` format and the client always put the `Content-Type` as the last header of the file upload (which curl always seem to do), this seem to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
echo '<title>Foo</title>'
echo '</head>'
echo '<body>'

echo "<p>Start</p>"

if [ "$REQUEST_METHOD" = "POST" ]; then
    echo "<p>Post Method</p>"
    if [ "$CONTENT_LENGTH" -gt 0 ]; then
    in_raw="$(cat)"
    boundary=$(echo -n "$in_raw" | head -1 | tr -d '\r\n');
    filename=$(echo -n "$in_raw" | grep --text --max-count=1 -oP "(?<=filename=\")[^\"]*");
    file_content=$(echo -n "$in_raw" | sed '1,/Content-Type:/d' | tail -c +3 | head --lines=-1 | head --bytes=-4  );
    echo "boundary: $boundary"
    echo "filename: $filename"
    #echo "file_content: $file_content"
    fi
fi
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'

exit 0
```

example upload invocation (which I used to debug the above):

```
curl http://localhost:81/cgi-bin/wtf.sh -F "MyFile=@myfile.txt"
```

- with all that said, THIS IS INSANITY! bash is absolutely *not* suitable for handling binary data, such as http file uploads, use something else. (PHP? Python? Perl?)

Comment: It's very educational regardless of the insanity.

Answer (score 11):

### The ways curl sends data

With fields:

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" https://example.com/resource.cgi
```

With fields specified individually:

```
curl --data "param1=value1" --data "param2=value2" https://example.com/resource.cgi
```

Multipart:

```
curl --form "fileupload=@my-file.txt" https://example.com/resource.cgi
```

Multipart with fields and a filename:

```
curl --form "fileupload=@my-file.txt;filename=desired-filename.txt" --form param1=value1 --form param2=value2 https://example.com/resource.cgi
```

For a RESTful HTTP POST containing XML:

```
curl -X POST -d @filename.txt http://example.com/path/to/resource --header "Content-Type:text/xml"
```

or for JSON, use this:

```
curl -X POST -d @filename.txt http://example.com/path/to/resource --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

This will read the contents of the file named filename.txt and send it as the post request.

For further information see

- [Manual -- curl usage explained](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)
- [The cURL tutorial on emulating a web browser](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html)

### Reading HTTP POST data using BASH

How to get the content length:

```
if [ "$REQUEST_METHOD" = "POST" ]; then
    if [ "$CONTENT_LENGTH" -gt 0 ]; then
        read -n $CONTENT_LENGTH POST_DATA <&0
        echo "$CONTENT_LENGTH"
    fi
fi
```

To save a binary or text file:

```
boundary=$(export | \
    sed '/CONTENT_TYPE/!d;s/^.*dary=//;s/.$//')
filename=$(echo "$QUERY_STRING" | \
    sed -n '2!d;s/\(.*filename=\"\)\(.*\)\".*$/\2/;p')
file=$(echo "$QUERY_STRING" | \
    sed -n "1,/$boundary/p" | sed '1,4d;$d')
```

The uploaded file is now contained in the $file variable, and file name in the $filename variable.

Comment: I don't see where do you read actual POST data? both `$filename` and `$file` variables are empty at the end

Comment: @sorush-r, how do you send it?

Comment: `curl --form "fileupload=@deploy.zip;filename=deploy.zip" --form branch=dev 10.0.0.167/cgi-bin/upload-rpm.bash`

Comment: @sorush-r, you have to write without `branch=dev`. Try to open your web site via `https://10.0.0.167/cgi-bin/upload-rpm.bash` (**or may be it is http** only and not https). **At first you have to be sure that your website is accessible via this address**. And then write it without `branch=dev`and without **LAST** `--form` (it is only to add if you send form field values) like follows `curl --form "fileupload=@deploy.zip;filename=deploy.zip" https://10.0.0.167/cgi-bin/upload-rpm.bash` OR `curl --form "fileupload=@deploy.zip;filename=deploy.zip" https://example.com/cgi-bin/upload-rpm.bash`

Comment: @sorush-r, and do not forget about `http` only `https` difference.

Comment: Sorry I have no access to my machine at work till Saturday morning. I will test and return back

Comment: No it does not. Binary data gets truncated. @hanshenrik s answer works