# expect script reading empty line

Tags: ssh, expect

I have a list of IPs that I am looping through to ssh into each of them and capture some logs. Currently, it will loop through all the IPs and do what I want, the issue occurs when it hits the last IP, after it is done with the last line, it attempts to spawn another empty line resulting in an error. (`spawn ssh root@`)

How can I prevent this error from happening?

myexpect.sh

```
set user user
set pass pass
set timeout 600

# Get the list of hosts, one per line #####
set f [open "/my/ip/list.txt"]
set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Iterate over the hosts
foreach host $hosts {
    spawn ssh $user@$host
    expect {
            "connecting (yes/no)? " {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
            "assword: " {send "$pass\r"}
    }

    expect "# "
    send "myscript.sh -x\r"
    expect "# "
    send "exit\r"
    expect eof
}
```

myiplist.txt

```
172.17.255.255
172.17.255.254
...
```

error:

```
[root@172.17.255.255: ]# exit  //last ip in the list
Connection to 172.17.255.255 closed.
spawn ssh root@
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
expect: spawn id exp5 not open
```

Comment: I think this has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165135/how-to-use-while-read-bash-to-read-the-last-line-in-a-file-if-there-s-no-new

Comment: In addition- I generally think using `expect + ssh` is a pain.  You might want to try a tool like Ansible- it will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text files end with a newline

```
first line\n
...
last line\n
```

So when you read the whole file into a variable, then split on newlines, your list looks like this:

```
{first line} {...} {last line} {}
```

because there is an empty string after the last newline.

The idiomatic way to iterate over the lines of a file in Tcl/expect is this:

```
set f [open file r]
while {[gets $f host] != -1} {
    do something with $host
}
close $f
```

Or, use the `-nonewline` option of [the read command](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/read.htm)

```
set f [open file]
set hosts [split [read -nonewline $f] \n]
close $f
foreach host $hosts {...}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the `-nonewline` and it worked like a charm!